# Calling init method of a UITableViewController instance with Three20's navigation modell

Tags: iphone, three20

i have a UITableViewController subclass instance called MainTableViewController within a three20 project. the mapping is set up like this:

```
[map from:@"tt://catalog" toViewController:[MainTableViewController class]];
```

after updating to xcode 4 and the current three20 v1.0.5. MainTableViewController's init method is not called anymore. Does anyone have a hint how to map to a view controller's init method without a parameter:

```
@implementation MainTableViewController
- (id)init{
```

The intro page to three20-style navigation points out *the no init case* and the *paramter case* : http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-URL-Based-Navigation

am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three20 expects that you use the designated initializer for UIViewControllers:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

Comment: thanks for clarification. i used a customized version of Three20 last year and forgot about that.